# How to set cursor position for non editable UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have not editable UITextView. When it get focus, the cursor position is on the begining. How can I set position of cursor? (I am using iPhone devise with Braille keyboard and when not editable UITextView get focus, I have text from the very begining of it, so I need to set position of cursor.)

Comment: Can you be more descriptive ?

Comment: If you have a non-editable UITextView, and then how can you edit it? And if you make it editable then where you want to put the cursor, at end or at start?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set cursor position at the end then use this delegate like this::

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
textView.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textView.text];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
return NO;
}
```

Remember one thing set UITextView property to yes for displaying cursor