# Making UITextView's row non editable and moving the cursor on the next line thereof

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I ve been facing a problem where in I want the UITextView's lines non editable along with the number of rows they occupy.
When clicked on the textfield it should start begin editing from the next line eg if first two rows are prepopulated with some text,I want the cursor on the third line and the first two rows of UItextView's non editable.

I ve been trying various solutions but the most likely of the lot was

[How to set cursor position for non editable UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020385/how-to-set-cursor-position-for-non-editable-uitextview)

But agastly !! it did not help..
Any further help would be much appreciated..

Thanks !!

Comment: Supposing your text field is to represent a list of sorts, you may best be able to achieve what you want using a table.  Table could list your non-editable items, and you can add a little UI to add to the table.  @Vishall, heal boy, heal!

Comment: No i cant use tableview in this case .If the string prepopulated is too long it might be of two lines or so depending on its length.

Comment: @AppleDelegate, you need to think on this a little more.  Table rows may be resized to fit text.  See `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  @Vishal, keep in professional 'Dude'.

Comment: Sorry @AppleDelegate, Jeremy & Rushi....

Comment: Ok this seems one way of getting this sorted.Cant it be done using UITextView's delegates like shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString*)text which m actually trying with ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found,

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)txtView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    //Check for back space character with @""
    if ([text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        //Check for the final character in the text view if its a new line character
        if ([txtView.text hasSuffix:@"\n"]) {
            NSLog(@"Yes I have it");
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.